# Regions where : $2u_{xx} + 4u_{xy} + 3u_{yy} - u = 0$ is hyperbolic, parabolic or elliptic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation

**Exercise :**

> Describe the regions of the $(x,y)$-plane where the following equation is hyperbolic, parabolic or elliptic :
>   $$2u_{xx} + 4u_{xy} + 3u_{yy} - u = 0$$

**Attempt - Question :**

In order to determine the regions, you have to work with the sign of the discriminant. My question though, is the following :

**Should the discriminant be yielded from the initial differential equation or from an equation in canonical form (applying transformations) ?**

If it should be yielded from the initial equation, then in the case of a PDE as :

$$au_{xx} + 2bu_{xy} + cu_{yy} + du_x + eu_y + fu +g = 0$$

we study the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$ and check its sign.

For my specific case, we have :

$$\Delta = 2^2 - 4\cdot 2\cdot 3=4-24<0$$

thus the equation is elliptic at every point $(x_0,y_0)$ in a domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^2$ of the PDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is off. It's

$$ \Delta = b^2 - ac = -2 < 0 $$

But in any case, the equation is elliptic everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is it does not matter whether you are working with the original PDE or in canonical form. It should give you the same answer.

Note that the person who previously answered the question has a 4 missing in the discriminant formula.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1206405)

Comment: I believe I provided an answer to part of the question. The other part was answered by another person so I just answered the following question:   "Should the discriminant be yielded from the initial differential equation or from an equation in canonical form (applying transformations) ?"